# Extract all duplicates based on a string

Tags: excel, vba

I have a spreadsheet were I have multiple ID duplicates. I need to extract specific duplicates based on a string in the column next to the ID using a vba code. For example:

```
Letter: t f t t t f f f                
ID:     1 1 2 3 3 3 4 4
```

I need to extract the duplicates that have the letter t with number 3, letter t number 1, and both f with number 4.

I've created the code below but its only pulling 1 of the duplicates.

```
Sub transfer_dups()
    Sheets("OP").Activate
    Dim OP As Worksheet
    Dim Final As Worksheet
    Dim lr As Integer  'lr = last row. Wanted to make it different from other parts of the code so there is not complications
    Dim i As Integer 'This is working as my row counter for the forloop

    'The code below will ensure that the data that was preciously populating the final filter sheet is cleared for a new process
    Sheets("Final").Select
    Range("A1:AQ300").ClearContents

    'Searching and selecting in the OP sheet (Opportunities)
    Sheets("OP").Select
    lr = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 2 To lr
        'if CELL B2=B3 and cell A2<>A3 then 
        If Cells(i, 8) = Cells(i + 1, 8) And Cells(i, 7) <> Cells(i + 1, 7) Then
            Range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(i, 48)).Copy 'This range may change if more columns are added
            Sheets("Final").Select
            Range("A300").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormulasAndNumberFormats 'Find the next available row
            Sheets("OP").Select
```

Thank you in advance for the help!

Comment: Notes: I highly recommend to read [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba). • Also you cannot use `Integer` for row counting variables. Excel has more rows than `Integer` can handle. Always use `Long` instead: `Dim lr As Long`

Comment: Where's the actual dupe checking code?

Comment: Where's the rest of your code? Looks like it was cut right in half.